# How to get siblings of multiple class

Tags: php, class, dom, xpath

I have these tags:

```
<div class="entry">entry #1</div>
<div class="subtitle">subtitle</div>
<div class="body">blah blah blah</div>
<div class="entry">entry #2</div>
<div class="subtitle">subtitle</div>
<div class="body">blah blah blah</div>
<div class="entry">entry #3</div>
<div class="subtitle">subtitle</div>
<div class="body">blah blah blah</div>
<div class="entry">entry #4</div>
<div class="subtitle">subtitle</div>
<div class="body">blah blah blah</div>
```

and so on. How can I get every content between each "entry" class in PHP? Using simple_html_dom_parse or XPath?

Comment: It is not clear to me what do you want exactly - can you post an example? Do you want all the elements between the first and the last `entry`?

Comment: No, picture that the <div class="entry">...</div> is a delimiter first and also the first line of the content I want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guessing that this is what you're trying to get:

```
<?php
// set up to parse our input
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile("./input.html");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// initialize array to put items in and initialize an item
$list = array();
$item = array();

$divs = $xpath->query("//div");
echo "len: {$divs->length}\n";
foreach ($divs as $div) {
  $class = $div->getAttribute("class");

  // each time we see an entry, add the item we've collected
  if ($class == "entry") {
    if (count($item) > 0) $list[] = $item;
    $item = array();
  }

  // otherwise add to the item we're working on
  else {
    $item[$class] = $div->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  }
}

// pick up the last item we were working on
$list[] = $item;

// and print the result
var_dump($list);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I wanted.